# postgresql list all the tables that are granted select to public

Tags: postgresql

I was wondering in postgres how can i find tables that are granted select(read) to public?
I know in \dp is showing priviliges of specific table but is there any function that can do \dp just public?

Comment: Check `information_schema`, IIRC there's rights information there. Haven't verified.

Comment: is this correct ?        
select schemaname||'.'||tablename
from pg_tables
where
has_table_privilege(
'public',
schemaname||'.'||tablename,
'select')
AND schemaname not in (
'pg_catalog',
'information_schema');